# Анимация во весь экран responsive iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, iframe, responsive

Вот пример для попытки задания **ширины** блока div, хелп! нужно сделать респонсив ширину

```
function an() {
    $("div").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
    height: '466',
    margin: '-10',
    borderRadius: '0',
    width: 'window.innerWidth' 
}, 555);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью css свойства поставленного на 100%

```
function an() {
    $("div").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    margin: '-10',
    borderRadius: '0'
}, 555);
});
```

Comment: хотелось бы конечно увидеть решение через **window.innerWidth & document.documentElement.clientWidth**